# Updating Objects through Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework set up that serves GET requests properly. After asking a previous question here, it should also be able to update objects properly. However, I'm not sure how I can update just one field in a model object. I have a Model ViewSet like this:

```
class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.filter(done = False).order_by('-unixTime')
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    paginate_by = None
```

And I have the urls registered through a router like this:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(task', views.TaskViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

The serializer is about as basic as they come right now:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'task', 'unixTime', 'done')
```

I'd like to be able to update the 'done' field of the Task object as identified by its primary-key id. I think I would need to use a partial_update model or path, but I'm unsure how to implement this. Also, just to give more information, the DRF browser view says the allowed HTTP methods are `GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `ModelViewSet`, just add put to your url's `as_view()` parameter.

You should have something like this in your url:

```
TaskViewSet.asView({'get': 'retrieve', 'put': 'update'})
```

i.e:

```
url(r'^your-regex$', TaskViewSet.asView({'get': 'retrieve', 'put': 'update'}), name='whatever')
```

You can then use `requests.put` to update it.

If you'd want to override the update method, you can add these to your ViewSet:

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Perform your custom actions here and probably call:
    super(TechyRetrieveUpdate, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```